# What is the best way to iterate over group_by(), summarise(), and unique output names based on df names?

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn how to iterate without using loops and both the `apply()` family of packages and `map()` family of packages have been pretty confusing to me.

Below is some sample code that is a generalized version of the data I'm working with. I start with a large dataset across many months or years. I have to filter it down to specific time periods of interest, and then I spit out separate summary tables to each page of an .xlsx to make comparisons for a report.

The real version of this code works perfectly fine, but I have many more summary/comparison tables to create than in this example, so I'd like to figure out the best way to do that functionally. I've been working with r for about a year and a half and can do things the long way, but making code more efficient is still a bit above my head.

Also, I can't quite figure out how to iterate over output names for the sheets...or any situation where I want to run multiple iterations that output unique file names based on the df name.

This is my first post here, so I apologize in advance for any formatting/protocol issues.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(janitor)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


rm(list=ls())

data <- tribble(
  ~Category, ~Date,        ~Area,     ~Count,
  "Fight",   "2021-01-04", "Area 1",  2,
  "Hug",     "2021-02-01", "Area 2",  4,
  "Dance",   "2021-03-21", "Area 3",  6,
  "Sleep",   "2021-04-18", "Area 3",  8,
  "Hug",     "2021-05-06", "Area 2",  2,
  "Dance",   "2021-06-30", "Area 1",  4,
  "Sleep",   "2021-01-29", "Area 1",  6,
  "Fight",   "2021-02-28", "Area 2",  8,
  "Dance",   "2021-03-15", "Area 3",  2,
  "Sleep",   "2021-04-08", "Area 3",  4,
  "Fight",   "2021-05-30", "Area 2",  6,
  "Hug",     "2021-06-10", "Area 1",  8
  
)

# define and order categorical variables

areas <- c("Area 1", "Area 2","Area 3")
cats <- c("Fight", "Hug", "Dance","Sleep")
data$Area <- factor(data$Area, levels = areas, ordered = TRUE)
data$Category <- factor(data$Category, levels = cats, ordered = TRUE)

# Filter and Summarise
this_14 <- filter(data, ymd(data$Date) >= ymd("2021-06-30")-13 & ymd(data$Date) <= ymd("2021-06-30")) %>%
  group_by(Category,Area,.drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Count)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = `Area`,values_from = total) %>%
  adorn_totals(where=c("row","col"))
this_14[is.na(this_14)] <- 0

last_14 <- filter(data, ymd(data$Date) >= ymd("2021-06-30")-27 & ymd(data$Date) <= ymd("2021-06-30")-14) %>%
  group_by(Category,Area,.drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Count)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = `Area`,values_from = total) %>%
  adorn_totals(where=c("row","col"))
last_14[is.na(last_14)] <- 0

prev_14 <- filter(data, ymd(data$Date) >= ymd("2021-06-30")-41 & ymd(data$Date) <= ymd("2021-06-30")-28) %>%
  group_by(Category,Area,.drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Count)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = `Area`,values_from = total) %>%
  adorn_totals(where=c("row","col"))
prev_14[is.na(prev_14)] <- 0  

# Create Workbook
file <- paste("Dev/output_tables_eff.xlsx", sep="/")
wb <- createWorkbook()

# Define Sheets
sheet1 <- addWorksheet(wb, "this_14")
sheet2 <- addWorksheet(wb, "last_14")
sheet3 <- addWorksheet(wb, "prev_14")


# Set Dataframes to export
writeData(wb, sheet = sheet1,this_14)
writeData(wb, sheet = sheet2,last_14)
writeData(wb, sheet = sheet3,prev_14)

saveWorkbook(wb, file = file, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you could make a minimal reproducible example and show your expected output. Your code breaks for me on `this_14`. An easy way to test this is to use the `reprex` package. Copy your code then run `reprex::reprex()`

Comment: @nniloc I used reprex to produce this mre. this code runs error-free and produces an xlsx file with three sheets, each with a different summary table

Comment: @nniloc I think the errors you're getting are because of a couple additional necessary libraries. I've added them above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using a function to create the summary tables and save them as tabs to the workbook. I used `purrr::map2` and supplied a list of start dates (e.g. 0, -14, -28) and list of names for the Excel sheets.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(janitor)
library(lubridate)

create_table <- function(start_date, sheet_name, df, wb) {
  
  df_out <- df %>%
    mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
    filter(Date >= ymd("2021-06-30") + (start_date - 13) & Date <= ymd("2021-06-30") + start_date) %>%
    group_by(Category, Area) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(Count)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = `Area`, values_from = total) %>%
    adorn_totals(where = c("row", "col")) %>%
    replace(is.na(.), 0)
  
  
  addWorksheet(wb, sheet_name)
  writeData(wb, sheet = sheet_name, df_out)

} 

wb <- createWorkbook()

map2(c(0, -14, -28), # desired start dates
     c('this_14', 'last_14', 'prev_14'), # names for the Excel tabs
     create_table, 
     df = data, 
     wb = wb)

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "output_tables_eff.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

---

Data

```
data <- tribble(
  ~Category, ~Date,        ~Area,     ~Count,
  "Fight",   "2021-01-04", "Area 1",  2,
  "Hug",     "2021-02-01", "Area 2",  4,
  "Dance",   "2021-03-21", "Area 3",  6,
  "Sleep",   "2021-04-18", "Area 3",  8,
  "Hug",     "2021-05-06", "Area 2",  2,
  "Dance",   "2021-06-30", "Area 1",  4,
  "Sleep",   "2021-01-29", "Area 1",  6,
  "Fight",   "2021-02-28", "Area 2",  8,
  "Dance",   "2021-03-15", "Area 3",  2,
  "Sleep",   "2021-04-08", "Area 3",  4,
  "Fight",   "2021-05-30", "Area 2",  6,
  "Hug",     "2021-06-10", "Area 1",  8
  
)

# define and order categorical variables

areas <- c("Area 1", "Area 2","Area 3")
cats <- c("Fight", "Hug", "Dance","Sleep")
data$Area <- factor(data$Area, levels = areas, ordered = TRUE)
data$Category <- factor(data$Category, levels = cats, ordered = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is an awesome approach. Thank you! This is exactly how I understood map() or map2() could work, but I couldn't work out the structure. This will be very helpful in transforming my actual script.